# how to clear user principals after logout?

Tags: java, jaas, principal

The case is easy: user clicks logout, goes to LogoutFilter and:

```
    HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    hreq.getSession(false).invalidate();

    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    httpResponse.reset();

    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
    httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

And on page login link is shown. The problem is easy: session recreated, but user principals are chached, so no login popup is shown and application uses cached principals, because request.getUserPrincipals() returns not null object.

The question is simple: is there any way to remove user principals too, so browser asks to log in again after logout?

Comment: How you do it depends on what authentication library you're using. The library/API must provide a way of doing it. For instance, in Spring Security you have to forward user to specific URL (or simulate such a call via the API).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just clearing the cache on logout, have a filter for your application that always sets those meta values to the response, for every request to a page in your application. This way, none of your pages will be cached. Clear your browser cache and try again. Does that fix anything?

Comment: I've added these lines into base template: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT" />, but no help with that. Principals are cached in request after the first login :(

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs out I would consider redirecting them (using a 302 redirect) to a 'logged out' page after you've invalidated their session.  That 'hopefully' will stop the request.getUserPrincipals() from returning anything.

BTW, the cache work that you're doing does nothing to your web applications cache.  What you're specifiying there is how web clients and web proxies should consider caching that particual request.  So, those values are used after the request leaves your server and goes out 'into the wild'.

Comment: I've tried this variant too: 

  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) getContext().getExternalContext().getResponse();
  HttpSession session = (HttpSession) getRequest().getSession(false);
  session.invalidate();
  response.setContentLength(0);
  try {
   response.sendRedirect(logoutUrl);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

But without luck :(